# OpenApi Smallrye: configure servers with application.properties file

Tags: openapi, quarkus, smallrye

I have the following API definition in a Quarkus application:

```
@OpenAPIDefinition(
            servers = {
                    @Server(url = "/")
            },
            info = @Info(
                    description = "Description of my interface",
                    title = "Title of my interface",
                    version = ".",
                    contact = @Contact(
                            name = "Some name",
                            email = "some email")
            ))
    public class MyApplicationextends Application {}
```

I would now like to move out the server definition to my `application.properties` (because I have a specific server path depending on the environment).
I was able to override the `info.version` using `mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.info.version=1.26.0`.
However I can't find how to override the servers. I tried `mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.servers=https://dummy2` but nothing shows up in the generated `openapi.yaml` file. If this possible?